# How to use masquerade to ip?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I have no experience on making NAT rules. I have a vpn that is using this:

```
# FILE: /etc/ufw/before.rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

This is working for now but I have two external ip addresses on the server, its masquerading to the default. I would like to set to where this should go but I don't know how. Should I change MASQUERADE to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from a few minor details, you can consider the [`MASQUERADE`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#MASQUERADE) target to be a special case of the more generic [`SNAT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#SNAT) target, which does allow to state the IP.

So your file could be replaced with:

```
# FILE: /etc/ufw/before.rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens3 -j SNAT --to-source 192.0.2.3
COMMIT
```

(or whatever the IP you wish to put).

Now you might have to adapt your VPN settings to match this, depending on your setup.

Comment: God! Thanks. I would never guess `to-source` I understood as a destination.